Solution for processing and serving video files
I am building a video editing webapp, so far, all the storage and processing has been done locally. The logic is set up like this:

User inputs a long form YT video link (around 30mins to an hour long).
Backend server downloads the video, processes it through and API (in some other server) and trims it (in my server) into 10-20 clips (1-2mins long).
The clips are stored in the backend and served to the frontend through an endpoint in my server.
The user reviews the clips and approves/rejects them accordingly.
Approved clips are sent to the backend and then processed again using an API (in some other server).
The returned, processed clips are served again to the front end for the user to edit the finishing touches and then rendered for download.

With the app features ready, I need to set up the app for deployment. So far this involved setting up a Wasabi s3 bucket for video storage and using Supabase to store paths and video information. Now I need to figure out:
1-How to serve the video files | I was thinking of using Google Cloud's CDN but I'm not sure if that is the right solution for me.
2-Where to host the server | As you can tell, even though most of the video editing and processing is done through API calls, the backend still handles the video download to temp files in the server and uploads to the wasabi bucket. For what I've learned about working with video files the fees with hosting services can add up pretty fast, especially if the selected service is not oriented towards media.
I want to make sure I'm in the right path before I commit to implementing these last 2 steps. So how would the architecture/logic need to look like for my particular use case and what tech stack would you suggest for this escenario without breaking the bank?
Please let me know if I can provide any more context if needed.
